# Merging in R takes forever

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I need to merge two dataframes - however it takes me forever. I had it run over night (>10h) and it still hadn't completed the work. Is this due to the dataframes being too big?

```
temp3 <- merge(analysis_data, temp2, by = 'Operationsnr', all.x = TRUE)
```

Where `analysis_data` is a dataframe measuring 907,499 rows by 77 cols, `temp2` is a data frame measuring 665,166 rows by 4 cols. Both have a column named `"Operationsnr", numeric class. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this R 4.0.0?

Comment: R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

Comment: Are the values of `Operationsnr` unique in temp2? Otherwise it will merge all matches for each row of `analysis_data` which could lead to huge 'temp3'

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing your data is an issue, but I suggest using data.table if you are manipulating big data.frames.

There are 2 options to merge the data, both equivalent, but when you want to do some data manipulation after the merge, option 1 would be preferable.

Also data.table uses 2 cores, and you can set more if needed. Do read all the vignettes with data.table if you go that route.

```
library(data.table)

analysis_data <- data.table(analysis_data, key = "Operationsnr")
temp2 <- data.table(temp2, key = "Operationsnr")

# option1
temp3 <- temp2[analysis_data]

# option2
temp3 <- merge(analysis_data, temp2, by = 'Operationsnr', all.x = TRUE)
```